How to Display Notification Data in Bottom Sheet When App is Killed?
I am working on an Flutter app where I want to implement the following functionality: When a notification is received, even if the app is killed, I want it to automatically open and display the notification data in a bottom sheet.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseBackgroundNotificationHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  log.log('firebase intializse');
  if (await OverlayPopUp.isActive()) {
    await OverlayPopUp.closeOverlay();
  }
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  log.log('firebase notification shows');
  await showNotification(message);
  Get.lazyPut(() => HomeScreenController());
  var findController = Get.find<HomeScreenController>();
  await findController.handleBackgroundNotification(
    message: message, showRide: true
  );

  await DeviceApps.openApp('com.xyz');
}

class HomeScreenController extends GetxController with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  Future<void> handleBackgroundNotification({required RemoteMessage message, showRide}) async {
    if (await OverlayPopUp.isActive()) {
      await OverlayPopUp.closeOverlay();
    }
    if (message.data['ride_info'] != "") {
      var data = jsonDecode(message.data['ride_info']);
      ride = Ride.fromJson(data);
      // this is for to show the bottom sheet when the notification received
      shoRide.value = showRide;
      update();
      await startTimer();
      update();
      shoRideValue = true;
      update();
    } else {
      updateConditionalLogic();
        }
      }
    }

Expected outcome:
When a notification is received, even if the app is not running (i.e., it's killed), the app should automatically open and display a bottom sheet containing the notification data.your text
Actual outcome:
Currently, when the app is killed and a notification is received, then the opens the app. but I want to implement opening of the app and displaying the notification data in a bottom sheet.

if your app is killed you cannot do anything afterwards
